# How to write a generic Max function

Tags: go, generics

How can I write a generic max function that would take 2 values given of type string or Int or float and return a max value.

```
type comparable interface {
    constraints.Integer | constraints.Float
}

func max[T comparable](x, y T) T {
    return T(math.Max(float64(x), float64(y)))
}

type customComarable interface {
    comparable |  ~string
}

func Max[T customComarable](x, y T) T {
    switch v := T.(type) {
    case string:
        if len(x) > len(y) {
            return T(x)
        } else {
            return T(y)
        }
    case constraints.Integer, constraints.Float:
        return T(max(x, y))
    }
}
```

This how I want the generic max function but go compiler is not happy with this I'm getting an error on `T.(type)`

```
T (type) is not an expression
```

I clearly see, things like this `Max("abc", 1)` would cause problem but given that. If I know all of the consequence of writing such function and ensure proper `x` and `y` type would it be possible to do something like I mentoined above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With generics it is pretty simple. Here is a more versatile function, which accepts variable number of arguments

```golang
func Max[T constraints.Ordered](args ...T) T {
    if len(args) == 0 {
        return *new(T) // zero value of T
    }

    if isNan(args[0]) {
        return args[0]
    }

    max := args[0]
    for _, arg := range args[1:] {

        if isNan(arg) {
            return arg
        }

        if arg > max {
            max = arg
        }
    }
    return max
}

func isNan[T constraints.Ordered](arg T) bool {
    return arg != arg
}
```

Comment: Fails (at least) if args[0] is  NaN. Generic numeric algorithms (even a simple Max) are never "pretty simple".

Comment: Good catch! Updated to match semantics of `math.Max` - 
it is still pretty simple though :)

Comment: What is this constraints package of which you speak?
https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/Go118NoConstraintsPackage